# Set pandas options for entire project

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following options set for a bunch of different modules in my project:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 300)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 15)
```

Is there a global setting?

Is there a best way to achieve this or is it common to just set them for each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quoted from [Options and Settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment) Python documentation.

> **Setting Startup Options in python/ipython Environment**
>
> Using startup scripts for the python/ipython environment to import
>   pandas and set options makes working with pandas more efficient. To do
>   this, create a .py or .ipy script in the startup directory of the
>   desired profile. An example where the startup folder is in a default
>   ipython profile can be found at:
>
> ```
> $IPYTHONDIR/profile_default/startup
> ```
>
> More information can be found in the ipython documentation. An example
>   startup script for pandas is displayed below:
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd
> pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 999)
> pd.set_option('precision', 5)
> ```

Comment: Is the  `profile` linux related?  I'm trying to find the startup directory for Python3.6 on Windows, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Moondra, Linux/Windows/Mac paths here: http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html

Comment: Thank you jpp. What about when we are not using Ipython? Is there a way to do this in native python?